# Can't catch a event SelectedItem to ViewModel on ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

In MasterPage, there are 2 Frame.
HomePage is at the first Frame ->

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:HomeVM/>
</Page.DataContext>
<ListView x:Name="lstHome" SelectedItem="{Binding lstHome_ItemClick}"
          Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding statusList}">
```

In HomeVM:

```
/// <summary>
/// ItemClick of ListView
/// </summary>
private Status _lstHome_ItemClick;
public Status lstHome_ItemClick
{
    get
    {
        return _lstHome_ItemClick;
    }
    set
    {
        if(_lstHome_ItemClick==value)
        {
            return;
        }
        _lstHome_ItemClick = value;
        //Excute the below code when the selection of listview has changed
        ItemClick(_lstHome_ItemClick);

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("lstHome_ItemClick"));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

When I click items on Listview-> don't call lstHome_ItemClick. Why?

Comment: is the `ListView` in the `Page`? try setting the `DataContext`on the `ListView` and see if that works

Comment: ListView in the HomePage. let DataContext="{Binding statusList}" then ListView is null

Comment: Set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the `Binding` .

Comment: Don't working..

Answer (score 1):

Set `binding` to be `TwoWay`. On [UWP the default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.mode.aspx) is `OneWay`.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstHome" SelectedItem="{Binding lstHome_ItemClick, Mode=TwoWay}" 
Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding statusList}" />
```